# Can't see boot option

Tags: boot

I have Dell-GX260 I installed latest ubuntu after windows 7, by selecting side by side option, everything finished well but when pc restarted, then automatically it loaded windows 7 without giving me option to choose between windows 7 or ubuntu. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you download the ISO image for the [**Boot-Repair tool**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and either burn it to CD or create a bootable USB drive.

After it boots, select the option to `Create a Bootinfo summary`.

[image: Initial Boot-Repair Window]

The tool should collect information and then display a message with a URL that will look like `http://paste.ubuntu.com/123456/`. Remember that URL ... especially the six digit number ... and add it to your question. This will allow us to see what might be wrong and make suggestions on how to fix it.