# How to manually install boot loader?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, system-installation, bootloader

My attempt to upgrade to 12.04 failed, so I burnt a 12.04 CD, and asked to do a full install, getting rid of all previous OS (I had Windows as well as 11.10). All seemed well until the very end when it said it had failed to install GRUB. I tried selecting different partitions to try in, with the same result. I can proceed without installing GRUB, but then it tells me I have to manually install the boot loader. A long Google session has failed to come up with any instructions to do this that I can understand. Help.

Comment: If the answer below works for you, great! If not, it would help to have more info about what your system looks like. Please consider using the [Boot-Repair tool](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to collect & post this info. I tried to outline how to do that [**here**](http://askubuntu.com/a/126420/52923)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Boot the machine using a Live CD.
2. Open a terminal.
3. Find out the name of the internal disk by using fdisk to look up the device's size.
   For example:

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
4. Install GRUB boot loader onto the proper disk (the example below assumes it is `/dev/sda`):

   ```
   sudo grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --root-directory=/ /dev/sda
   ```