# Need to manually install bootloader

Tags: bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manually install boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader)

Grub failure when installing 12.4 alongside Windows 7 (50 GB partition for 12.4), need to manually install bootloader.  Where can I find this?

Comment: Why not installing 12.04 again.

Answer (score 5):

**install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

1. Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu"
3. Connect internet
4. Open a new Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Then type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

***Using Boot-Repair***

[image]

**Recommended repair**

1. launch Boot-Repair from either :

   a. The Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

   b. Or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)

   c. Or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
3. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a Boot-Repair Live USB or Live CD. This will repair Grub and allow you to boot Windows and Ubuntu again. You can find instructions on creating a Boot-Repair Live USB or CD [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_%3a_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair).