# Bootloader install failed - ubuntu 20.04, boot-repair did not help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I'm having issues while trying to install ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 8.1. I am compeletely new to this so i followed [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/) (I should mention that I had no option to ,install ubuntu alongside...' it was not showing up). After that I got an error as in the title ,bootloader install failed' i selected the option to install it manually and restarted my computer.
After that i followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192639/need-to-manually-install-bootloader). Here's the [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3Zw5Rj3frz/) and the final messege i got:

*,The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit ([www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd)), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.'*

I did use rufus while preparing my USB to ensure that it would be in UEFI compatibility (edit: file system: FAT32, target system: BIOS or UEFI). At this point I have no idea what to do, other suggestions I found online seem to be way beyond my understading.

Alternatively is there I way to actually use what I already installed at this point?

Comment: Did you started the live-cd in Uefi mode?

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Rufus creates either UEFI only or BIOS only versions. The ISO is for both and other tools create a bootable flash drive that is both and then in UEFI boot menu have to to choose the UEFI entry not the non UEFI entry. rufus  select gpt (uefi non csm)  Screen shows MBR UEFI-CSM is BIOS, Most want gpt & UEFI
http://rufus.akeo.ie/
Shows screen with gpt & UEFI which is what most now need.
https://superuser.com/questions/497672/how-to-create-an-uefi-bootable-usb-stick-from-an-iso Is Windows example but otherwise same for Linux.

Comment: Your pastbin log:   <pre>=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.</pre>this indicates that all your hard drives aren't use GPT and without GPT you can only write into MBR, that means that you must use BIOS mode or you must format your Hard Drive where you will install Linux to GPT partition table

Comment: _"Rufus creates either UEFI only or BIOS only versions."_ That is incorrect. By default, Rufus creates a dual UEFI+BIOS version of Ubuntu bootable media. It's only if you __change__ the default partition scheme to GPT that it will become UEFI-only. But this is not the default, you have to actively change the option. And Rufus even tells you under _Target system_ that, if you go with the default, the media will be for either BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: Pastbin line 104 indicates sdb is gpt.  Since it has no BIOSboot partition, even though it has an MBR, it cannot boot in legacy. Definitely a Windows install in UEFI mode.  Your boot-repair session  is in legacy mode, so that's how your machine is set to boot, legacy if possible, then UEFI if not. Change that and boot the install media in UEFI mode.