# Why don't I get the Grub bootloader when I boot from my HDD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, usb-installation

I have an external Seagate HDD that I [boot Windows 10 from](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/). I wanted to dual boot from it, so I installed Xubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 using the normal install procedure for Xubuntu (normal installation, *not* persistent live-USB)

I partitioned the drive into three partitions (Windows, Xubuntu and swap), set the mount point to the Xubuntu partition and installed Xubuntu there.

I believe I set the "device for bootloader installation" to the external HDD in question.

The installation completed sucesfully, and when I browse the Xubuntu partition (from another Linux system), I can see the file structure of Xubuntu, and it looks like a totally sucessful installation.

However, when I try to boot from this HDD, I only get Windows 10 booting automatically, and no Grub bootloader.

This leads me to question whether I actually chose this device for the bootloader, although I could have sworn I did.

Is there any method through which I can confirm that I did indeed install Grub to this HDD?

How can I find out why I don't get Grub while booting from this HDD?

FWIW the computer I used to perform the installation boots just like before and it only had Windows 10 on it.

As requested by @Pilot6, I took my normal Windows/Xubuntu laptop, booted Xubuntu, connected the external HDD in question, and ran `sudo parted -l`.

Here is the output:

```
pal@pal-Vostro-3546:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for pal: 
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB  524MB   primary  ntfs            boot
 2      525MB   208GB  207GB   primary  ntfs
 3      208GB   317GB  109GB   primary  ext4
 4      317GB   320GB  3146MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Seagate Expansion (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  262GB  262GB   primary  ntfs            boot
 2      262GB   498GB  236GB   primary  ext4
 3      498GB   500GB  2097MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: This means that you installed grub somewhere else.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see. So I guess I could repeat the process, making **sure** I select the drive for "bootloader installation". Or can I just install Grub by itself, now, without doing the whole installation again? BTW I added another sentence of detail to the question.

Comment: You can install `grub` on that disk without re-installing Xubuntu.

Comment: @Pilot6 Like the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/126586/451919)?

Comment: Not exactly. Boot from LiveUSB and find out the name of your external disk, then I can give you the correct command. Or post `sudo parted -l` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Or I'll just boot up my normal Xubuntu laptop, connect the external HDD, and do it from there?

Comment: It is a good idea too.

Comment: @Pilot6 Alright, I have done that. According to `gparted`, the external drive is  called `sdb` and the `ext4` partition I installed Xubuntu on is called `sdb2`.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 It is done.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install `grub` to your external HDD. Connect it to an Ubuntu machine and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
sudo umount /mnt
```

This will install `grub` to `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Alright, I get Grub and Xubuntu boots, but I can no longer boot Windows 10. Grub merely lists "Windows boot manager" and if I select it, I get "error: invalid signature".

Comment: This is some kind of a Windows problem. I have no idea what signatures they use. Is it a grub error, or a Windows boot loader?

Comment: I'm not sure, but Windows worked from the external HDD before I installed Grub.

Comment: How does it look like? Is it on the purple screen? Try to boot on another machine. Win 10 doesn't like when you boot on a wrong one.

Comment: Alright I booted from another machine and got another error. I think I'll start over with the whole installation, using another computer for the installation process.

Comment: Make sure `grub` is on the correct disk.

Comment: Alright, yeah. Thank you very much for your time and attention!