# Toshiba laptop won’t boot from SSD after installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, dvd, toshiba-satellite

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.03 from a DVD via a USB CD/DVD drive onto my Toshiba Satellite U920T laptop, erasing the Windows 8 that was on there. The installation went fine and as requested I removed the DVD at the end of the process.

However, when the computer restarts the following message comes up

```
Insert system disk in drive.
Press any key when ready..
```

I have looked in the Bios and the computer is set to start on the SSD/HDD. Putting the DVD back into the DVD drive allows me to repeat the installation process, which I have done with the same result. Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> while starting the computer and selecting the SSD/HDD brings me back to the `Insert system...` message.

The boot log is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/25748557/
This is the log after creating the NTFS partition suggested below and reinstalling Ubuntu.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: It seems the boot loader is not installed. Have a look at this post to do it manually: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader

Comment: Unfortunately That fix brings up an error message.   grub-install: error: cannot open directory ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc’; No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Toshiba Satalite C55-B series computer that gave the same error.
It required a system recovery partition to be first on the HDD, and the UEFI partition to be second.
It can be empty but had to be there.

Create a 1 GB partition formatted NTFS. Then, use the remaining space to install ubuntu.

Note: if your EFI firmware does not have OS boot options, you have to move and rename grub's file in the EFI partition.
/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi has to be copied to /EFI/boot/ and renamed to bootx64.efi.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have created an NTFS partition and reinstalled Ubuntu. Unfortunately, It still isn’t booting from the SSD. I am struggling to find and rename the files in the EFI partition when running Ubuntu from the DVD. Can you advise on this?

Comment: Be sure you installed in EFI mode. There will be a small (~500MB) partition formated FAT32 and flagged as ESP (EFI System Partition). You will have to remove the flag temporarily to mount and edit the contents.

Comment: In Gparted it shows the ESP as /dev/sda but I don’t seem to be able to mount it using the Sudo mount -a command.

Comment: sda is the HDD ... the partition is sda1, or sda2 , etc

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. I am going to try by starting from scratch again, reinstalling windows, using an USB drive to load Linux and keeping Windows to see if that helps.