# Stuck with install of dual-boot on “remove installation media”

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install a dual-boot system on my windows computer (HP Spectre).  I have turned off secure boot and fast boot, partitioned my hard drive (I gave 100GB to Ubuntu) and created a USB Drive that was formatted to have the Ubuntu boot on it (I don’t have a DVD drive on my computer, so I have to use USB).  I used Rufus 3.1 to accomplish this.  I also changed my boot order to boot first to the USB HDD.

When I boot up with the USB drive inserted, it boots to the GRUB Menu.  I have tried both "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu".  Both bring me to an Ubuntu loading screen, and then to one that says “Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER”.  If I do not do anything, it will just stay there.  If remove the USB drive and press enter, it shuts down the computer.  If I DON’T remove the USB drive and just press enter, the same occurs.

After the shutdown, I have tried to restart.  Restart without the USB drive loads Windows 10.  Restart with the USB drive brings me back to the GRUB startup screen.

I have tried multiple USB ports and USB drives, so that is not the issue.  The computer is a 2018 model laptop with intel i7, 16GB RAM, and a SSD - power or RAM shouldn’t be a problem. I have also tried the “check for problems with the disk” option - it shows no issues. Heat is also not an issue - I tried this in the refrigerator and freezer, and it occurs no matter how hot or cool the computer runs.  At this point, I’m pretty much out of steps.  Has anyone had the same difficulty?  Does anyone know how to fix it?  Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to follow all of the steps in the mentioned article, and it does not solve the problem.  The question fails to explain a working solution to the problem - instillation with the USB media stops at the stage mentioned above, and there’s is no way that I can find (including boot options menu) to get to the boot without the drive installed.  Also, even if I select the “try Ubuntu” option, I get the same issue - I cannot get into a live Ubuntu Session beyond the Ubuntu loading screen

EDIT #2:  I don't know what caused the problem, but I was able to fix through this process:
When at the grub bootloader, select the "try ubuntu" option, and press "e" for edit command.  In the edit command screen, add acpi=off to the end of the first command.  That fixed it for me.

Comment: "Both bring me to a Ubuntu loading screen, and then to one that says “Please remove the instillation medium, then press ENTER”.  If I do not do anything, it will just stay there.  If remove the USB drive and press enter, it shuts down the computer." This is expected behavior.  Since your actual problem seems to be that your computer boots to windows after your ubuntu install, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: I read those articles - they didn’t solve this problem.  I don’t believe that that Ubuntu installs at all, even when it says to remove the media.  I read through that whole article and honestly can’t find how it helps...

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Some with newer HP have said using UEFI to change boot order now works, but efibootmgr which Ubuntu uses still does not work. Work arounds if using UEFI to change order does not work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 1):

It seems your GRUB isn't installed correctly. Your best shot is to try reinstalling the GRUB bootloader. This should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/a/126586/767158

If that doesn't work, perhaps you need to turn off secureboot: there should be a setting in you BIOS/UEFI for this.

If that still doesn't work, try turning off fast boot, again in the BIOS/UEFI.

I'm not an expert, but I don't think temperature will affect your boot.

Cheers,
DT

Comment: Hi DT - I really appreciate that, but when I looked at this, it is telling me that I need to boot into a live session of Ubuntu from the USB drive - I can’t get there, even if I use the “try Ubuntu” selection with the Live USB inserted.  Is there a way to reinstall GRUB from windows?

Comment: Sorry @CameronPodd, it appears that A) I didn't understand your initial problem correctly, and B) you're beyond my level of experience here. That said, you may want to try redownloading the Ubuntu liveusb. That's helped me once before. Are you using 18.04 or something older?

Answer (score 0):

> If remove the USB drive and press enter, it shuts down the computer

You could press the `F11` key on your laptop and it takes you straight to the boot options menu from which you can select the Ubuntu option

Comment: In this menu, there is no Ubuntu option.  There is OS Boot Manager and a “boot from EFI File” option.  When I reinsert the USB drive I get an EFI file that I can boot from.  There are two options - grubx64.efi and bootx64.efi.  Bootx64 brings me back to the grub menu, and grubx64 gives me an error that the option did not authenticate.  In either case, removing he USB Drive will stop any process, saying that it cannot find the memory.