# Need help with Ubuntu/W7 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, boot-repair

I'm having an issue setting up a dual boot system. I previously had Windows 7 Ultimate on my machine and have just installed Ubuntu, which worked just fine.

Problem is, I can no longer boot Windows 7, by selecting Windows Boot Manager from the boot menu, the screens shows "Loading Files" but after finishing, it jumps right back to the boot menu. Windows is installed on an SSD and Ubuntu was installed on a different HDD, in which I created a partition for Ubuntu before installing.

I have already tried the Boot Repair software as well as Rescatux from live boot. Does anybody have an idea what to try next?

[EDIT] I tried the method described here: [How to manually install boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126541/how-to-manually-install-boot-loader)

Installed on the disk containing w7.
The terminal output says the installation went without problems, but it still jumps back to boot menu after loading files, it's as if nothing happened

Tried reinstalling Ubuntu and selecting the Boot location to be on the Disk with Windows Boot Manager, but it didn't work as well.

Comment: The bootloader should be installed on your first hard drive, where windows resides.
You can do this when selecting custom partitioning scheme in ubuntu installer, and still install the OS on the second hard drive. 
There is something tricky about a dual boot with and windows.
The bootloader (grub) must be installed on top of window's, and as long as you don't do the other way (windows bootloader on top of grub), it will be able to run both systems.

Comment: So I just reinstall Ubuntu and put its bootloader on the w7 SSD?

Comment: If that's about one's opinion I would suggest only one crypted linux system.
Now @Jalle